# In SDL2, when is SDL_JoystickInstanceID different than SDL_JoystickOpen(n)?

Tags: sdl

In SDL2 [the documentation suggests](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_JoystickOpen#Remarks) that the number used to open the joystick (between 0 and `SDL_NumJoysticks()`) can be different than the   `SDL_JoystickID which;` used to reference the stick in events. When are these numbers different?

Comment: The thing to try is to connect 2 ️ and open them from range(n-1 .. 0) instead of the usual 0 .. n-1

Comment: I just tried that on a Linux box with 3 logitech joysticks, and the numbers match up whether I open them in up or down order. My guess is the IDs are in a separate namespace (numberspace?) for a good reason, like on some other platform they might be opaque handle values cast to ints or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code should assume the numbers are always different (even if they happen to be the same sometimes). For example, when you get a [`SDL_ControllerAxisEvent`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_ControllerAxisEvent), the `which` field should match the value of [`SDL_JoystickInstanceID()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_JoystickInstanceID) for *one of* your open joystick handles. You can use [`SDL_JoystickFromInstanceID()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_JoystickFromInstanceID) to get the joystick handle from the `which` value.